# Как вывести множество файлов при добавлении изображения в finput="file"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как вывести множество файлов при добавлении изображения? Пока выводится только один файл и переписывается если добавлять другое. Спасибо

```js
const inputFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.input-file');
console.log(inputFiles)
if (inputFiles) {
  let pattern = /((?:.(?!\(\d+\)))+.)(?:\(\d+\))?\..+/
  inputFiles.forEach((inputFile) => {
    const id = inputFile.getAttribute('id').replace('input-file-', '');
    const fileName = document.querySelector(`#filename-${id}`);
    const fileClose = document.querySelector(`#fileclose-${id}`);
    inputFile.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
      fileName.textContent = this.files[0].name.match(pattern)[1]
      fileName.classList.add("_active")
      fileClose.classList.add("_active")
    });
    fileClose.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      fileName.classList.remove("_active")
      fileClose.classList.remove("_active")
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.left-form-calculator__files {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: -10px -5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-inputs {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 175px;
    height: 53px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-input-value {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f8f8fa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2857142857;
    color: #91919b;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name._active {
    display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close{
   position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer
    min-width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f5912d;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close:hover::before {
    background: #af671e
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close._active {
    display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__file {
    display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1eb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f5912d
}

.left-form-calculator__label-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}

.left-form-calculator__label-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2857142857;
    color: #91919b
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - A Pen by paralax</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
  <!--1-->
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file" id="input-file-1">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file-1">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename-1"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close" id="fileclose-1">x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
    <!--2-->
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file" id="input-file-2">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file-2">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename-2"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close" id="fileclose-2">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для загрузки нескольких файлов в input есть атрибут multiply.
Совсем недавно я делал форму для файлов, вот ссылка на репозиторий:
https://github.com/Dlazder/file-form

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Да я бы в комментарии написал, но у меня заблокированы они были, поэтому написал ответ. Мой репозиторий отлично отвечает на вопрос реализации формы файлов, там простой код и ничего лишнего, поэтому он более чем развернуто отвечает на вопрос)